# Source doesn't support parameter called 'IIS Web Application Name' error with Sitecore 9 installation using web deploy

Tags: deployment, sitecore-install-framework

I am using Sitecore SIFLess program 1.5 version, which is similar to the SIM tools, the Sitecore 9 installation fails with message:

```
msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
install-SitcoreConfiguration @xConnectParams
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you installing Sitecore 9 update-1 with previous configuration json files.

Comment: I have cleared the files and removed the databases created by the `SC9 Powershell` though. but the scripts is the same. I am using SIFLESS tool btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue was solved, by doing the following steps:

- removing all the databases.
- Rewrite moduels was missing
- The Sitecore PSGallery and SitecoreGallery were not Trusted Repo
- Removed the IIS directory.
- Rerun the SIFLESS tool.

it showed up like this, and the problem was solved.

[image]

I have also compiled the list of commands for the powershell, that are prerequisites for the SC9 installation

https://gist.github.com/isaadansari/63bd6ee4a1a80b40dcc0113739f4bb1b

Comment: re "The Sitecore PSGallery and SitecoreGallery were not Trusted Repo" how did you set these to be trusted?

Comment: run these in powershell `Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted` and `Set-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue installing Sitecore 9 locally and discovered my mistake was pointing at the

`Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip`

package instead of the

`Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip`

package when using the `Install-SitecoreConfiguration` Powershell cmdlet for the main Sitecore install.

Answer (score 0):

This issue indicates that the installation script is not able to set the values of parameters in xp0-xconnect.json file -

line 428: { "Name": "IIS Web Application Name", "Value": "[parameter('SiteName')]" }

It happens when it is not able to access properly the zip file mentioned in script-

Line 28: $XConnectPackage = (Get-ChildItem "$SCInstallRoot\Sitecore 9.1.1 rev. 002459 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip").FullName

In our case it occured when my colleague unzipped the "Sitecore 9.1.1 rev. 002459 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip" and again zipped it using WinRAR.

To resolve this error, he replaced the "Sitecore 9.1.1 rev. 002459 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip" created by him with the original zip file downloaded from sitecore site.